# In a Matrix Fieldtype, how does one call a function before all the rows are saved using save_cell()

Tags: matrix, fieldtype

In a custom Matrix fieldtype I have, the save_cell() function is used to process the fieldtype data for each row. It seems this function is called on a per row basis, so not called once.

What I would like to know is how to call a function just once, before all the rows are saved. A kind of before_save() function or something.

Alternatively if this is not possible, then I wondered how we can obtain the number of the save_cell() row we are on. I can then call a function based on this row number being 1.

Thanks